# Set default location in telerik bing map provider

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Am using telerik bing map and i need to search locations in a particular country without specifying that country name.
"Is it possible to set default country or any location name in the map?" Any kind of help is appreciable....

Thank you..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `radMap.Center` property to center the map and apply desired zoom level to get the desired view. Then for the search queries, based on the location suffix the country name to keyword to perform location relevant searches.

Reference:

1. Centering Map at desired location: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmap/how-to/bring-a-location-into-view.html
2. Putting a mark at desired location: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmap/how-to/put-a-mark-on-the-clicked-location.html

Comment: How can i search a location of a country without specifying that country name? For example, Salem is a city name which resides at many country but when i search "Salem", it should show the location marker as "Salem, Tamilnadu, India". How can i acheive this using bing search provider?

Comment: Say from coordinates you find that the map is centered to India. And someone searches "Salem", you can suffix it with "India" and show search results for "Salem India". Alternatively, you can find results within a given radius from the location you centered the map to.

Comment: Set the search options appropriately. Reference: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/api/html/T_Telerik_Windows_Controls_Map_SearchOptions.htm